# How to fix date-fns errors after package upgrade in Angular app?

Tags: angular, node-modules, date-fns, npm-update

After upgrading packages in Angular app using `yarn upgrade`, I now get multiple errors like shown in the image below.
The version of date-fns has not changed (2.16.1), so the problem is something else.

I tried downgrading to 2.15.0 and 2.11.1 as suggested here https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/1683, but that doesn't fix it. Send help.

Tried adding these lines to tsconfig.json:

```
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
```

[image: Error message]

Error message: Cannot augment module 'xxxx' with value exports because it resolves to a non-module entity.